# Show that $(1+p)^n \equiv 1 + np \pmod{p^2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Show that $(1+p)^n \equiv 1 + np \pmod{p^2}$.

I attempted this by induction and could not make it work. Any hints?

Comment: Try the binomial theorem.

Comment: Why didn't induction on $n$ work? $(1+p)^{n+1}=(1+p)^n(1+p)$.

Comment: *Why* didn't it work?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
(1+p)^n = \sum^n_{\ell=0}\binom{n}{\ell}p^\ell.
\end{align}

Edit. For the inductive step, assume $k=n$ holds, that is
\begin{align}
(1+p)^n \equiv 1+np \mod p^2.
\end{align}
Then consider $k=n+1$ and observe
\begin{align}
(1+p)^{n+1} \equiv (1+p)^n(1+p) \equiv (1+np)(1+p) \equiv 1+np+p+np^2 \mod p^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Induction should work just fine, actually. Think about the first few steps: for $n = 1$, we have $(1 + p)^1 = 1 + 1 \cdot p$, so we're good so far.

For $n = 2$, $(1 + p)^2 = (1 + p)(1 + p) = 1 + 2p + p^2$, which is $1 + 2p$ modulo $p^2$.

For $n = 3$, $(1 + p)^3 = (1 + p)^2(1 + p)$. Since we already know that $(1 + p)^2 \equiv 1 + 2p \mod p^2$, $(1 + p)^3 \equiv (1 + 2p)(1 + p) \mod p^2$. But $(1 + 2p)(1 + p) = 1 + 3p + p^2 \equiv 1 + 3p \mod p^2$.

Try this same approach for $n = 4$ and $n = 5$. You should see a pattern in the steps that can be repeated for an arbitrary $n + 1$ in your induction step.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
for any $0 \le m < n$,
$(1+p)^n
\equiv \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{k}p^k
\bmod p^{m+1}
$.

This is because 
the rest of the terms
given by the binomial theorem
are divisible by $p^{m+1}$.